# Which library are LO headers belonging to?

Tags: compiling, libraries, configure, header-file

I'm trying to configure [`liquidsoap`](http://savonet.sourceforge.net) and compile it from source. The `./configure` process gets stuck at this point:

```
checking lo/lo.h usability... no
checking lo/lo.h presence... no
checking for lo/lo.h... no
configure: error: LO headers not found.
```

Now it's quite difficult to find out which `lib` or package is needed. I searched the package manager (`aptitude` from Debian) for `lo` but this is quite pointless. I also was asking google for `LO headers` but I was not getting much results.

What does `lo.h` belong to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be a package called `liblo-dev` on Debian that should provide this header. Simply install it using apt-get or aptitude:

```
aptitude install liblo-dev
```